# Sync async job via Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, start-job

I have a PowerShell function that I need to get the value from a new-job to a variable within the script, without "sleeping the script."

My idea is something similar to the following...

```
Function async() 
{
    $scriptblock = { 
                        #Do Something 
                        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
                        write-output $argsfromFunction 
                   } 
    return $(
                start-job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock 
                          -ArgumentList $argsfromFunction 
            );
}
function getresult() 
{ 
    return $( get-job ( async() ) | receive-job ) 
}
#do it when the async() stop running without interrupt the script and set it to $global:var1
```

What is the simple way to accomplish my task?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend learning PowerShell a little more before tackling jobs as they require a more robust understanding of the pipeline and how PowerShell handles inputs and outputs.

But you can use the following:

```
$jobToRun = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { #DoStuff }

while ( [Boolean]$( $jobToRun.JobStateInfo.state -ne "Completed" ) )
{
    # Do some stuff in script while job is running
}
$results = Receive-Job -Job $jobToRun
```

Then depending on the output of the Script Block you can parse through `$results` for what you want. You also don't have to wait for the job to complete in a loop but you need to have a way to handle if the job isn't completed or taking a long time. Also once you're more comfortable with PowerShell I'd highly recommend looking into Runspaces instead of jobs as each job requires a new instance of PowerShell which can get memory intensive. Boe Prox wrote a great article on utilizing them and even provided his own custom module to make them a similar format as jobs.

Also if you wanna put them in a function you can just wrap `Start-Job`/`Receive-Job` inside of it and set it equal to a variable. You don't need to return the output in PowerShell as return is just a way to exit a function, script, or script block, each result of the statements inside the function will return from a function output, and if you wanna read more on what Return means you can here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return